# Got "No such layer" response through RESTful API

Tags: layers, geoserver-rest-api

We publish a feature type and layer called "ice" through GeoServer RESTful API and then we close the computer without exit the GeoServer instance normally. After that, we restart the computer and GeoServer service, found this layer 'ice' could not be found through restful api 'geoserver/rest/layers/ice'. But the 'featuretype.xml' and 'layer.xml' could be found in the 'ice' dir under data_dir.  After that，I found the problem is the DataStoreInfoImpl value in featureType.xml is not consistent with that in datastore.xml. After I correct featureType.xml and restart GeoServer , the layer could be loaded as expected.

But I wonder what is the ‘DataStoreImpl' meaning, and if the datastore for example PostGIS, or the GeoServer was crashed unexpectedly and restart later, those layers published before would not work since 'DataStoreImpl’ has been changed?

The datastore is PostGIS. And the log in GeoServer start process shows:
Failed to load actual store for FeatureTypeInfoImpl[ice]
25 八月 15:26:26 WARN [org.geoserver] - Failed to load resource
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must be part of a store

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add some more information to your question - what sort of data store is ice? what does the log file say is the issue?